# installing or setting up barry in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: installation

I'm trying to setup or install barry on ubuntu 12.04 laptop to be able to sync my blackberry to thunderbird or evolution as I would to do on windows, but I'm struggling to do so. I really need a step by step way to setup or install barry so that I can sync my barry to thunderbird or evolution 100% and proper. I've tried looking on the internet, but can't find proper step by step in installing barry. I've tried linberry, but doesn't have the feature in syncing your calendar, contacts and so on to thunderbird or evolution. Please assist me in this.

Answer (score 0):

I have no personal experience but there is information [here](http://www.netdirect.ca/software/packages/barry/installdebian.php)

To summarize:

- Edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` to include

  `deb http://download.barry.netdirect.ca/barry-latest/ ubuntu1204 main`
- Update your apt key ring with the new key

  `gpg --keyserver pgp.mit.edu --recv-key B6C2250E`

  `gpg --armor --export B6C2250E > barry.key`

  `apt-key add barry.key`
- Install

`sudo apt-get install barry`

Comment: This is helpful but does not include instructions on how to sync Barry with Thunderbird as OP requested.

Comment: It does say 'installing *or* setting' up...