# Barry installition

Tags: 12.04, wubi, permissions, blackberry

In an attempt to install Blackberry application (Barry) following guide listed at: 
[installing or setting up barry in ubuntu 12.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/165821/installing-or-setting-up-barry-in-ubuntu-12-04)

I got the error:

> Could not save the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/barry.list. You do not have the permissions necessary to save the file. Please check that you typed the location correctly and try again.

Right clicked on folder `sources.list` and under permissions I found that Root have create and access permissions while group and others have access only permissions then at the bottom *"you are not the owner, so you can not change these permissions"*.

Am new to Ubuntu (Wubi)and not sure how to change these permissions am the only user and my password is/was root installation password.

Comment: Could you please tell the previous command that triggered the error?

Answer (score 0):

Ok..So so to edit the file use

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

When you type the given command, it will ask for password.
Give it your password (which is the same as the root password and enter)

Then when you try to save it will save.

After that just follow the guide whose link you have provided.

For your help-

the **sudo** command (along with other commands) is used in Linux to perform all the tasks that the root (super user) can.

sudo stands for super user do.

gedit is a text editor.

so sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list

opens the file /etc/apt/sources.list
in text editor gedit
with root privileges

Comment: sudo: gedit /etc/apt/sources.list command not found, although gedit is installed,  Thanks

Comment: please follow the link given at the top of the page  http://askubuntu.com/questions/92379/how-do-i-get-permissions-to-edit-system-configuration-files   and see if it helps you, otherwise post here.

Comment: It worked after a repository update.

Comment: ok...if my answer helped you, please mark it as solved :)