# How to install BlackBerry Tools on Ubuntu 13.10

Tags: sync, blackberry

How can I install BlackBerry Tools? I have Ubuntu 13.10.

When I launch start.exe, the answer is `error loading archaive`
Please, be so kind, and help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can't, the software is only available to Windows and Mac. Your best bet is to get the software running under [Wine](http://www.winehq.org/).

Comment: This [Wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PortableDevices/Blackberry) says to use a program called [Barry](http://sourceforge.net/projects/barry/), onwhich there are some installation instructions [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/165821/installing-or-setting-up-barry-in-ubuntu-12-04)

Answer (score 0):

If you mean BlackBerry tools for **Android development**, first install either Eclipse or Android Studio (there's a Linux package), then [download the appropriate SDK plug-in](http://developer.blackberry.com/android/tools/).

Hope that helps!